# Find if date is in range using index match in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I need to find if the id in column ID2 is in ID_Master **AND** if the corresponding date in col Date3 falls between the dates in Start_Date & End_Date.

I have the following layout:

ID_Master         Start_Date      End_Date     ID2          Date3

testid1               1/1/2016          2/1/2016      testid2     1/3/2016

I tried the index match formula, but have no luck. I feel its something simple, but i dont seem to have any luck :(
appreciate the help this forum provides!

Comment: What do you want to do if you have a match? Is this for conditional formatting, or another column showing results?

Comment: @lurker If there is a match, I would like to display a "y" else "n". This is to sum other corresponding columns.. I can work with a y/n for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a simple COUNTIFS():

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$500,D2,$B$2:$B$500,"<=" & E2,$C$2:$C$500,">=" & E2)>0,"y","n")
```

Edit as per you comment.

Comment: thanks a ton mate!! this works like a charm!! you saved me alot of pain i have been going through for 4 hours now! THANK YOU

Comment: @marv no problem, please come back in a few minutes and mark correct when SO will let you.

Answer (score 1):

This `IF` statement would also work:

```
=IF(AND(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,A:A,1,FALSE)),FALSE,TRUE),IF(E2<C2,IF(E2>B2,TRUE,FALSE)))=FALSE,"N","Y")
```